# Is it possible to set a border or linear gradient to an SVG element - line

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, d3.js

I am using d3.js to build a timeline which has axis.

Now, in order to make the time range more visible i have increased the axis's tick to a certain width and length as shown in the image below [image]

The gray and white stripes below are actually the tick lines of the axis which looks something like this in terms of code:

```
<g class="tick" transform="translate(1241.7410071942445,0)" style="opacity: 1;">
    <line y2="-457px" x2="0" y1="55px" style="stroke-width: 202px;"></line>
    <text y="3" x="0" dy=".71em" style="text-anchor: middle;">Oct 05</text>
</g>
```

Now, I want to create a border around these stripes. I tried something like this:

```
<g class="tick" transform="translate(1241.7410071942445,0)" style="opacity: 1;">
    <line y2="-457px" x2="0" y1="55px" style="stroke-width: 202px; border: 1px solid black">  </line>
    <text y="3" x="0" dy=".71em" style="text-anchor: middle;">Oct 05</text>
</g>
```

As expected, this clearly did not work and I cannot find any way to achieve that. Any Ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make an SVG "line" with a border around it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8845426/how-to-make-an-svg-line-with-a-border-around-it)

Comment: I have looked at it but in my case it will be tricky because these lines are drawn by d3 itself as a part of axis. If I were drawing these lines, I would have rather used rect instead of lines for this purpose

Comment: but the problem is that lines do not have filling, they can have only one color (from stroke). I believe you won't be able to do what you want without adding new lines or replace it by a rect.

Comment: Is it possible using linear gradients?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an SVG filter to add an outline around a line.

```
<svg width="200" height="200" 
     viewPort="0 0 200 200" version="1.1"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

  <defs>
    <filter id="outline" x="-20%" y="-20%" width="140%" height="140%">
      <feMorphology operator="dilate" radius="1"/>
      <feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0
                                           0 0 0 0 0
                                           0 0 0 0 0 
                                           0 0 0 1 0"/>
      <feMerge>
        <feMergeNode/>
        <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"/>
        </feMerge>
      <filter>
  </defs>

      <g filter="url(#outline)" >
    <line x1="40" y1="120" 
          x2="120" y2="40" 
          stroke="red" 
          stroke-width="10"/>
      </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Awesome, this worked. I added the filter around the entire axis (not just the line), and it seemed to work. THanks